Assigning an individual quota to a user assigned to a territory
I’m trying to understand if it’s possible to set an individual quota for a user (Cookie Monster, who is active) I’ve assigned to a territory.
When I attempt to add a quota for the user Cookie Monster (this is a dev org), I only see the ‘forecast manager’ listed.
I suspect this might be because only forecast managers (Beaker B in this case) can have a territory quota, but I’m unsure.
If this is the case, it seems this is quite a limitation because it feels like a pretty common scenario to assign quotas to reps within different territories.
Perhaps there is a workaround?


